# GnuRadio: Clock Recovery MM: imu out of bounds

Tags: signal-analysis, gnuradio

I have created a flowgraph, [based on an example of Michael Ossmann](https://github.com/mossmann/im-me/blob/master/garage/garage-decode.py), which takes in a signal, and should output bits.

I need to use the clock recovery MM block, which I do not fully understand yet. However, after reading some blogposts, I am quite sure that I can leave most of the settings default, except for the Omega one. Here's my flowgraph:

[image: flowgraph]

When running this flowgraph, it gives me the following error:

```
thread[thread-per-block[5]:<block clock_recovery_mm_ff (9)>]: mmse_fir_interpolator_ff: imu out of bounds.
```

While searching, I stumbled upon [this piece of code](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/repository/revisions/ce3d887a47b47cb2d5351e14066ceb56b2b3c892/entry/gr-filter/lib/mmse_fir_interpolator_ff.cc) in the source of GnuRadio:

```
int imu = (int)rint(mu * NSTEPS);   
  if((imu < 0) || (imu > NSTEPS)) { 
    throw std::runtime_error("mmse_fir_interpolator_ff: imu out of bounds.\n"); 
  }
```

So, I suspect it is not due to my Omega setting (which might be wrong, I have to play with that setting), but that it is due to my Mu setting, which is just the default (0.5). However, I understand that Mu needs to be between 0 and 1, so I do not really understand what the problem is. Anyone who does?

Environment details:

- GNU Radio Companion 3.7.7.1
- Running a GNU Radio live DVD in a virtual machine (VirtualBox 4.2.12) on Windows 7.
- Using Volk machine: ssse3_64

Comment: I'd recommend closing this here, since [this discussions on the GNU Radio mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-08/msg00354.html)  advanced quite a bit.

Comment: My initial error still persists (see my last comment there), even after having implemented the hints provided by the replies on that thread.

Comment: I know, and it's been sitting on my "as soon as I have time, let's look at this" list for far too long...

Comment: Why should it be closed then?

Comment: The approach was that you're more likely to get good replies if people could concentrate on one forum. I can fully understand if you don't agree with that, so that's why I humbly recommended closing it :) don't worry, I won't stop replying to you on either forum!

Comment: by the way, *can* you share the samples you use, as I can't reproduce what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

The M&M clock recovery block has a bug in it, such that it can't reliably handle more than 8 samples per symbol without inadvertently dropping samples.  That interpolating resampler alignment bug *may* also be responsible for generating mu values outside of [0.0, 1.0].

I'd strongly recommend, downsampling the input from 2.5ksamples/symbol down to 6 or 8 samples /symbol before the M&M block.